# Tomcat display 404 windows

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I try to lauch my server with ApacheTomcat to create an API like [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm)

I create the .war file into `/webapps` so i have `/webapps/UserManagement.war`
When I try to launch the server and open `http://localhost:8080` it's ok but with `http://localhost:8080/UserManagement` or `http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users`, It display a 404 Error.

How Tomcat works ? I read some previous subjet posted here and read again the tutorial i did not find where i did something wrong

**Content from /webapps & /webapps/UserManagement**

```
[root@localhost webapps]# ls ; ls -R UserManagement
docs  examples  host-manager  manager  ROOT  UserManagement  UserManagement.war
UserManagement:
META-INF  UserManagement.war  WEB-INF

UserManagement/META-INF:
MANIFEST.MF  war-tracker

UserManagement/WEB-INF:
classes  lib

UserManagement/WEB-INF/classes:
com

UserManagement/WEB-INF/classes/com:
tutorialspoint

UserManagement/WEB-INF/classes/com/tutorialspoint:
User.class  UserDao.class  UserService.class  web.xml

UserManagement/WEB-INF/lib:
aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b05.jar  hk2-utils-2.5.0-b05.jar       javax.inject-2.5.0-b05.jar   jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar  jersey-container-servlet-core.jar  jersey-media-jaxb.jar    osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
hk2-api-2.5.0-b05.jar                 javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar       javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar  jersey-client.jar   jersey-container-servlet.jar       jersey-server.jar        persistence-api-1.0.jar
hk2-locator-2.5.0-b05.jar             javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar  javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar    jersey-common.jar   jersey-guava-2.24.jar              org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar  validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
[root@localhost webapps]#
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <display-name>USER MANAGEMENT</display-name>
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Jerset Restful App</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.package</param-name>
                        <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
                </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <serlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</serlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**LOGS**

```
18-Nov-2016 09:53:24.974 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M13
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.066 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 3 2016 20:59:41 UTC
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.067 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.068 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.068 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/conf/logging.properties
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.068 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.068 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.068 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.068 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.068 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.069 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/temp
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.069 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.\
path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.718 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.820 INFOS [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.838 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.840 INFOS [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.840 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2273 ms
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.913 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service Catalina
18-Nov-2016 09:53:25.913 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M13
18-Nov-2016 09:53:26.000 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/UserManagement.war de l'application web
18-Nov-2016 09:53:27.375 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were\
 scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Nov-2016 09:53:27.594 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/UserManagement.war has finished in 1 578 ms
18-Nov-2016 09:53:27.595 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/ROOT de l'application web
18-Nov-2016 09:53:27.635 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/ROOT has finished in 40 ms
18-Nov-2016 09:53:27.636 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/docs de l'application web
18-Nov-2016 09:53:27.679 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/docs has finished in 44 ms
18-Nov-2016 09:53:27.679 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/examples de l'application web
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.169 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/examples has finished in 490 ms
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.170 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/host-manager de l'application web
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.360 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/host-manager has finished in 190 ms
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.361 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/manager de l'application web
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.429 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/manager has finished in 68 ms
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.434 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.439 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
18-Nov-2016 09:53:28.439 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2599 ms
18-Nov-2016 10:00:59.030 INFOS [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Repli (undeploy) de l'application web ayant pour chemin de contexte /UserManagement
18-Nov-2016 10:00:59.080 INFOS [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/UserManagement.war de l'application web
18-Nov-2016 10:00:59.624 INFOS [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13/webapps/UserManagement.war has finished in 544 ms
```

Comment: what about your `web.xml` file?

Comment: Assuming that you did all the steps of the tutorial, have you tried this URL http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users ?

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` or `index.jsp` in the root of your webapp ? If not that it the reason why `http://localhost:8080/UserManagement` gives a `404` error since the root of your webapp has no corresponding mapping

Comment: Check please :C:\program files\apache software foundation\apache-tomcat{ver}\logs\catalina.out

Comment: Nicola Filotto. 404 for the full URL || Jackk. Log is huge, i did many try. I add logs from today only for the moment

Comment: Of course it should be 404 because there is no such resource at the root context. If you have followed the tutorial exact the same way, you have a resource here http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users

Comment: explain more, it doesn't help. First time i use Tomcat it's maybe obvious for you but not for beginners

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the project on the website. It's on developing a simple RESTful web service, and it doesn't contain a default  **index.jsp** or **index.html** file. So it's ok that you get a 404 error when you try to access `http://localhost:8080/UserManagement`.

To test your application, you have to run the url `http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users` in your web browser as mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: I have 404 with the full URL, Indeed my post is not clear about ti i'll correct it. I first try the full URL then some test. /UserManagement was to test URLs

Answer (score 0):

I also met the 404 not found,try this:

jersey.config.server.provider.package

->

```
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
```

tips:enter code hereI am a newer and my English is poor